# DialogFlow Implicit Invocation

Tags: dialogflow-es

I was hoping to get guidance into how I may use Dialog Flow to shorten the process of getting information from an action.

For example, I would like to provide the following command:

"Ok Google, Ask my test app what is the capital city of the US."

However, I currently need to say:

"Ok, Google, open my test app"

I would then need to wait for a response before providing the name of the country that I need the capital city for.

I'm finding the guidance from the Google documentation difficult to follow.

Do I need to create an implicit invocation in order to give the parameter with the launch command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you want to trigger intents from the launch commands you have to add those intents as a deep link / implicit invocation, to do this the only thing you have to do is create an intent which can handle the parameter and then add it to the implicit intents under the actions on google integration section in Dialogflow.

You don't have to create any intent specially for implicit invocation, you can just use the ones you have already created for normal conversations.

I've written an [guide](https://blog.mirabeau.nl/nl/articles/creating_friendly_conversational_flows_using_google_deep_links/61fNoQEwS7WdUqRTMdo6J2) to implicit invocations / deep links for Google Assistant if you need more help or infomation. Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nP2YJEUEv88&feature=youtu.be) with the end result

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. I think I'm on the right track, how far it seems that dialogflow excuse the welcome intent instead of the intent specified in the implicit intent field. is there a way I can override the welcome intense so that it doesn't run if the implicit intent is called?

Comment: There is not a way to do that, if you setup an intent as implicit it should run if you add a training phrase for that intent in the launch command, so make sure what ever you are adding to the launch command doesn't normally trigger the welcome intent too.