# Google Assistant actions.intent that pass the complete text to the app

Tags: java, android, kotlin, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I am making app like if user say's to google assistant OK Google

1:-What's my Average Temperature in XYZ App (want Send text or query for average temprature to XYZ App)

2:-What's my average Oxygen level from 27 jun date to date in XYZ App (want send text or query with params to XYZ App)

3:-Show my all data of Temprature in XYZ App (want send query for all data to XYZ App)

How i identify the user text or query?

I want to know which actions.intent youtube use when i ask

xyz song in youtube

Google assistant open the app and play xyz song(in which intent youtube receive song name).

right now i am using simple

```
actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE
```

It simply open the different screens from the app when user says temperature or Spo2 with empty text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DialogFlow Implicit Invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59118613/dialogflow-implicit-invocation)

Comment: No i donot want to use assistant sdk withint the app like chat boot

Answer (score 0):

To run a particular song Use [Search Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) to make a search

You will get a list according to the user search, from the list of items, use the item URL to open a particular youtube video. when you will call a URL, it will open the Youtube application on the device if it is installed on a user device.

Comment: but i want to know which intent or mechanism youtube use for google assistant that youtube search the song from the google assistant.